# SharePoint list form - Waiting (TTFB) is too high

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, performance, edit-form, response

I have a SharePoint list form which is taking average 20 seconds time to load. When I check in Chrome Developer Tools, I found that Waiting(TTFB) is taking around 18 seconds to load.

[image]

This issue is only on this one SharePoint list's Display and Edit Forms. New item form of the same list and other pages are loading normally.

I have also created new Edit and Display forms from SharePoint Designer, but on those new forms also waiting TTFB time is same, no difference.

What is the solution to reduce the Waiting(TTFB) time?

Comment: Just wondering did you find a resolution for this? I am editing this because I believe to have found a resolution for this.
I deleted the forms and added them again to the list and the TTFB issue was resolved.
I created a copy of the list, deleted list 1 forms, pasted them from the new list in SP designer.

Answer (score 2):

TTFB is a metric of SQL sending data to SharePoint. You'll want to start out by looking at SQL performance (disk primarily, but also memory and CPU) followed by network response time. Verify you have <1 ms ping times between your SharePoint servers and active SQL server(s).

Comment: Yeah, but For other pages this Waiting TTFB is very less. Only for this one list Display and Edit Forms, it's taking too much time. Waiting TTFB is around 18 seconds.